# replace a future title with a text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to replace a title when clicking on it by a text input in order to modify the title, I'm using this code :

```
<div style="font-size: 70%;"><h2 class="outer"><?php echo $designation; ?> </h2></div>
```

this div is loaded using another script and therefore is not on the original page, so I think we must use the delegate method.

Here is the jquery script I'm using to turn its background color to pink:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#right").delegate("h2","click",function(){
       $("h2").css("background-color","pink");
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Any idea how to replace the title in this div by a text input tag ? and any idea how to submit the modification to the database once I click outside the input field ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to "update" the title you need to replace the html in the `h2` element with an `input` element which is set to the current title. Then you need to add a listener so when the user clicks out of that input box it sends an AJAX request to some other site on your server that is setup to update the database with the new title. [**This code does the trick**](http://jsfiddle.net/4S2JE/2/)

```
$(function(){
  $('#right').on('click', 'h2', function(){
    var $h2 = $(this);
    var old = $h2.html();

    if(/<input type="text"/.test(old))
      return;

    $h2.html('<input type="text" value="' + old + '"/>')
       .find('input')
       .focus()
       .on('blur', function(){
         var value = this.value;
         $.post('/new_title.php', {title: value})
          .done(function(){
            $h2.html(value);
          })
          .fail(function(){
            $h2.html(old);
            alert('Could not update title');
          });
       });
  });
});
```

Make sure you change the url in `$.post` to the url where you setup your listener. An example listener would be like:

**new_title.php**

```
<?php

require('DB.class.php'); //Require your DB Class

if($_POST && $_POST['title']){
  DB::updateTitle($_POST['title']);
}

?>
```

Comment: when I click on the text field it prints this : "<input type=" and outside of the text input : '"/>'

Comment: @TarikMokafih - My apologies. It was running the function again once you clicked in the input. I have added a check to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML:

```
<h2 style="cursor:pointer;">Click Me</h2>
```

Your JS:

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "h2", "click", function() {
   $( this ).html( '<input type="text" value="yourValue">' ).find('input').focus();

    $("input").focusout(function(){
            $("h2").html( this.value  );
    }).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        return true;
    });
});
```

For submit your input you can use simple $.ajax POST request into ".focusout" function OR something like Aust $.post code. This is your options. just send your data.

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedhbi/sWxb7/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you were trying to achieve. But where does the element with id "right" come from? Is this the one that is loaded from another script? In that case, try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#right', function(){
        $("h2").css("background-color","pink");
    })
});
```

Comment: the element with id "right" is the big div where I will load this new div

Answer (score 0):

To replace div content, use code:

```
$('div').html('<input type="text" name="abc" />');
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but have you any idea how to put title's text in this new text input and then modify it

Comment: You should clarify your question with reference to blocks in code (title, text input) and what do you exactly want to achieve. Currently I can't give an answer as I'm not entirely sure what you want get answered.

Comment: Here is what I want to do : http://jsfiddle.net/3FKzH/
except that in my case the h2 tag is not on the original page but will be loaded after by a script.
Thank you